# Можно ли вручную вызвать всплывающий адрес как у ссылок?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот, например, если в примере ниже навести курсор на ссылку, то в левом нижнем углу браузера появится всплывающая подсказка с адресом, куда ведёт эта ссылка.

```html
<a href="to Equestria">Hover over here!</a>
```

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы такая браузерная подсказка появилась после наведения на обычный блок или на ссылку без атрибута `href`?

Comment: Посмотри тут. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444770/how-to-display-text-in-the-browser-status-bar Без javascript точно нельзя.

Comment: Можно сделать с помощью **css**. Вот готовый пример - ***https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp***

Comment: Вам нужно вывести хинт или заполнить статусбар браузера?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov незнаю как официально называется вот эта штука, появляющаяся внизу браузера при наведении на ссылку со href, но вроде как ваш ответ об этом самом.

Comment: @DenisRoss прочитал тот пост, открыл для себя `window.status`, спасибо, но, к сожалению, он не рабочий.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но мне нужен был не тултип, а конкретно браузерная фича и способы её вызова.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно заполнить статус бар в браузере, то это можно сделать установив значение `window.status`. Но не все браузеры разрешат такую операцию

А если нужна всплывающая подсказка, то достаточно у элемента установить атрибут `title`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.show-status').mouseenter(function() {
    window.status = $(this).data('status');
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    window.status = '';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-status" data-status="Hint1" title="Title1">Button1</button>
<button class="show-status" data-status="Hint2" title="Title2">Button2</button>
```

Comment: Есть информация в каких браузерах это работает и включено по дефолту?

Comment: Нет, тайтл мне точно не нужен, это можно откатить.